# How to set projection in Find(filter, options) in MongoDb using C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, projection

I get compile errors with the following syntax.

```
var index = ...;
var projection = Builders<Thing>.Projection
  .Include(a => a.Name)
  .Include(a => a.Stuff[index]);

var options = new FindOptions<Thing, Thing> { Projection = projection };
var filter = Builders<Thing>.Filter.Where(a => a.Name == name);

var output = await _dbContext.Things.Find(filter, options)
  .SingleOrDefaultAsync(token);

return output;
```

The computer is unhappy with my options, requiring them to be non-generic. However, if I use `FindOptions` instead of `FindOptions<A,B>`, there's no property `Projection` to be set. Since I do need my projection, I'm bound to use the generic version.

I also noticed that I could use `FindAsync(...)`, instead of `Find(...)`, which seems to accept the generic version. Regrettably, it's not an option because the signature of the method is to return `Task<Thing>` and I'm getting `Task<IAsyncCursor<Thing>>`. I get stuck on how to de-cursorify, obtain the single element in the set (unique naming guarantees that) return the task of correct type. (If I go `ToList()`, the asynchronicity is killed.)

There's no many examples out there.

I have a working mongo script for that but it's translating it into C# that the big obstacle.

```
db.getCollection('things').find(
  { name: "blobbo" },
  { "stuff.shazoo": 1, name: 1 }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your models look like this:

```cs
public class Thing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Stuff[] Stuff { get; set; }
}

public class Stuff
{
    public string Shazoo { get; set; }
    public string Foofoo { get; set; }
}
```

you can get the desired result via aggregation like so:

```cs
var projection = Builders<Thing>.Projection.Expression(
    t => new Thing
    {
        ID = t.ID,
        Name = t.Name,
        Stuff = t.Stuff.Select(s => new Stuff { Shazoo = s.Shazoo }).ToArray()
    });

var things = await collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(filter)
    .Project(projection)
    .ToListAsync();
```